# Do you shoot a gun or fire a gun?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

> He shot a gun.
>   He fired a gun.

Do these sentences mean the same thing? I often hear the former, but it has always felt wrong to me (as if another gun were the target).

Comment: What dictionaries have you consulted and what did they report that confused you?

Comment: eats fires and leaves.

Comment: @Susan - Oooooh, a [fire-eater](https://www.google.com/search?safe=on&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1219&bih=827&q=fireeater)! Cool.

Comment: The OED strongly supports both uses.

Answer (score 6):

In general I tend to use *shot* when I am aiming at something and the emphasis of the statement is the intent to hit what was being aimed at.

> He *shot* the deer in the field.

I use *fired* in two situations, 1) when the gun is not being specifically aimed

> The gun has only been *fired* 3 times.

or when the emphasis of the statement is on the specific action of pulling the trigger or the hammer falling

> He aimed the gun and *fired*

Answer (score 2):

Consider a Brown Bess Musket;

[image: Brown Bess Musket]

You must first load "powder" and "ball" (also known as a "shot") in order to "fire your powder" which will "shoot your ball". Since modern rounds integrate powder and ball; a modern gun may be considered to both "fire" and "shoot" at once. Unless there is a "[misfire](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misfire)"; in which case the round is not shot.

Comment: But could the *modern gunner* be considered to do both?

Comment: @Jim I believe it is a historical distinction; pulling the trigger causes a hypothetical hammer to fall simultaneously firing and shooting. If there's a separate charge and round then it is different.

Comment: I'm only pointing out that the question asks what the gunner can do (shoot and/or fire). How the gun accomplishes the action may be interesting, but it is irrelevant.

Comment: Again, I think if we're talking modern firearms the terms are synonymous.

Comment: You say "fired", I say "shot". You say "to fire", I say "to shoot". You say "firing", I say "shooting". And we're both saying the same things.

Comment: I understand what you were thinking now.

Comment: @Jim Only exception I can think of is "dry-firing"; I would not use "dry-shooting". But there we're "not" firing or shooting.

Comment: Actually, you are making a good point. I just came from the gun show, and I know a little bit about this topic. I have intentionally fired several arms that I did not shoot, and sometimes they were not "dry" or powderless.

Comment: @Jim Are we now talking about mis-fires? Rare, but I have heard the term.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the two terms have the same meaning.  One could say, "I shot the gun out of his hand," so the verb *to shoot* can be both transitive and intransitive.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question was for when another gun *isn't* the target.

Comment: Indeed, *shoot* can even be bitransitive.

Answer (score -1):

You fire a gun; the gun shoots projectiles such as bullets.

Comment: Without any evidence that this is actually an (authoritative) answer, I down vote.